# loop and use the index of the number as filename

Tags: c++, string

I am not very well versed in c++, what i wanted is in the line

```
cv::imwrite("/home/ryan/PCN-FaceDetection/predictions/j.jpg", img);
```

i wanted to string format the i variable which is being looped and make it the filename.

In python it would be like

```
for i in range(0, 26):
   imwrite("/home/ryan/PCN-FaceDetection/predictions/{}.jpg".format(i), img)
```

How do i do this in C++?
Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
{
    cv::Mat img =
        cv::imread("../imgs/" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg");
    cv::TickMeter tm;
    tm.reset();
    tm.start();
    std::vector<Window> faces = detector.DetectFace(img);
    tm.stop();
    std::cout << "Image: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time Cost: "<<
              tm.getTimeMilli() << " ms" << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < faces.size(); j++)
    {
        DrawFace(img, faces[j]);
    }
    cv::imwrite("/home/ryan/PCN-FaceDetection/predictions/i.jpg", img); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED
```

Comment: You want `"/home/ryan/PCN-FaceDetection/predictions/" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg"`.

Comment: Amazing , let me try this

Comment: This worked .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the overloaded string addition symbol, while converting the numerical `i` to a string, with the help of [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/), like this:

```
"/home/ryan/PCN-FaceDetection/predictions/" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg"
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EDNxrzlAc6ijmgpp)</kbd>